# Not able to combine <enablewebscript> and <clientcredentials> in a single wcf endpoint behavior

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-behaviour

I am trying to combine enablewebscript and clientcredentials in a single wcf endpoint behavior so that I can fetch a x509 certificate via thumbprint.
But when I define both the above mentioned tags in a single endpoint behavior, the service is not working as expected.

Is there any way to combine enablewebscript and clientcredentials in a single wcf endpoint behavior?

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CombinedBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
            <clientCredentials>
                <!-- Configure your client credentials settings -->
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `<enableWebScript>` enables the endpoint behavior that makes it possible to consume the service from ASP.NET AJAX web pages.

To call a WCF service from an ASP.NET AJAX client, the service must be configured with the `WebHttpBinding` and the `WebScriptEnablingBehavior` must be added to the endpoint behavior collection. This can be done in configuration by adding the WebScriptEnablingElement in service-side like below:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<services>  
        <service name="Microsoft.Ajax.Samples.CalculatorService">  
            <endpoint address=""  
                behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior"   
                binding="webHttpBinding"  
                contract="Microsoft.Ajax.Samples.ICalculator" />  
        </service>  
    </services>  
    <behaviors>  
        <endpointBehaviors>  
            <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">  
                <enableWebScript />  
            </behavior>  
        </endpointBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

So you can't combine `<enableWebScript>` and `<Clientcredentials>` together.

More details could be found in this docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.configuration.webscriptenablingelement?view=netframework-4.8.1